# IIS7, web.config transforms, msbuild are not playing nicely.

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I have an issue where a transformed value is being added to the web.config without a space before the closing end tag, which is then changed by IIS later on.

web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="TranformationUsed" value="base" />
<appSettings>
```

web.release.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="TranformationUsed" value="release" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

web.config (published via release):

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="TranformationUsed" value="release"/>
</appSettings>
```

If IIS 7 decides for any reason it's going to make some edits to web.config it takes it upon itself to correct this and the web.config ends up looking like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="TranformationUsed" value="release" />
</appSettings>
```

Publishing from visual studio 2013 or msbuild removes the space, IIS adds it back in. This is incredibly frustrating when you have a number of lines it has decided to correct and you have version control software that doesn't like the differences.

Does anyone know if there is there a way to get the publish via visual studio 2013 and/or msbuild to leave the space in?

Does anyone know if there is there a way to get IIS to stop correcting the spaces in the file? IIS also decides to pull some lines together into a single line.

Comment: Have you tried using SetAttribute instead of replace?